# fixing a diagram in Homework Problem Sheet

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, technical-drawing

could someone make this homework problem looks good-looking

[image]

here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}% just to show the page margins
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove demo option in actual document
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Problem 1 : ] 
\end{description}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-0.5,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
  \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.8,sloped,auto]{\SI{10}{\meter}};
  \draw[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.2,sloped,auto]{\SI{8}{\meter}};
  \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
  \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{\SI{3}{\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}\raggedleft
Two ladders, one 10 meters long and the other 8 meters [long], have been placed in a trench as indicated in the opposite figure. Their point of intersection, M, is 3 meters from the base of the trench. What is the width of the trench?
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Otherwise this question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: see my update !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can better use a proper class for a problem sheet. Here I used `exam` class.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\qformat{\bfseries Problem \thequestion: \hfill\null}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
Two ladders, one 10 meters long and the other 8 meters [long], have been placed in a trench as indicated in the opposite figure. Their point of intersection, M, is 3 meters from the base of the trench. What is the width of the trench?
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,2.5)},x=0.6cm,y=0.6cm,font=\footnotesize]
  \draw (-0.5,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
  \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.9,sloped,auto]{\SI{10}{\meter}};
  \draw[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.05,sloped,auto]{\SI{8}{\meter}};
  \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
  \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{\SI{3}{\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `exam` class, you may do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}% just to show the page margins
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove demo option in actual document
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
%\section*{Problem 1 :}   %% or subsection
\noindent\textbf{Problem 1:}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
Two ladders, one 10 meters long and the other 8 meters [long], have been placed in a trench as indicated in the opposite figure. Their point of intersection, M, is 3 meters from the base of the trench. What is the width of the trench?
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,2.5)},x=0.55cm,y=0.55cm,font=\footnotesize]
  \draw (-0.5,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
  \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.8,sloped,auto]{\SI{10}{\meter}};
  \draw[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.1,sloped,auto]{\SI{8}{\meter}};
  \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
  \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{\SI{3}{\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: this class make problem in my paper so i can't use it

Comment: @Educ OK. But the approach (of `minipage`s) should work.

Comment: could you adapte to looks like yours

Comment: @Educ Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

Is this better?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% just to show the page margins
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Problem 1 : ] 
\end{description}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
Two ladders, one 10 meters long and the other 8 meters [long], have been placed in a trench as indicated in the opposite figure. Their point of intersection, M, is 3 meters from the base of the trench. What is the width of the trench?
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,4.5)}]
  \draw (-0.5,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
  \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.8,sloped,auto]{\SI{10}{\meter}};
  \draw[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.2,sloped,auto]{\SI{8}{\meter}};
  \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
  \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{\SI{3}{\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: without lines i want it to be like Exam sheet

Comment: @Educ. I think "without lines" is comment out `geometry` package or just suppress its `showframe` option.

Comment: how to scale the figure and keep it in right like what Harish Kumar did